# "cannot open display: :0" error when using sudo with any GTK app

Tags: sudo, gtk

I want to run *gmsartcontrol* (UI tool for smartctl) which needs to be run as root in order to access the drives and read their SMART status.

However doing this:

> sudo gmsartcontrol

I get this error:

> No protocol specified
>    [gtk] cannot open display: :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For graphical applications use gksu:

> gksu gsmartcontrol

If it is not installed on your system you can get it via:

> apt-get install gksu

Answer (score 0):

As your login user, do

```
xhost +


xhost root
```

root being added to access control list

```
vim /etc/sudoers
Defaults env_keep="XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY TZ PS2 PS1 PATH LS_COLORS 
KRB5CCNAME HOSTNAME HOME DISPLAY COLORS"
```

Optional

```
1952  adduser $USER wireshark
1953  chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap
1954  setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/dumpcap
1955  getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap
```